# what does (decline ) mean here?

Tags: verbs

I have bought something on the internet and for some reasons the item returned back to the seller. when I asked the seller to refund me he sent me this message .

> The seller has declined to have the item returned.The dispute will be settled according to the agreement.

I looked on longman dictionary and find that decline has many meaning:

1. say no
2. to decrease in quantity or importance.

so does the seller say that wont refund until the item returned 
or he decrease in importance of the problem

Comment: refuses to allow the return of the item. **""politely refuse (an invitation or offer).
"Caroline declined the coffee"
synonyms: turn down, reject, brush aside, refuse, rebuff, spurn, repulse, dismiss;  Google Dictionary"**

Comment: Is that said because of the declining tone of saying "no", compared to inclining tone of a question?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you see something of the form "This person declined that thing", it means that the person said No to receiving that thing. So, in this case, the seller refused to accept the return.

When "decline" means "decrease", it is always *intransitive*. The amount of water in a tank may decline, but you cannot "decline the amount of water", in the sense of making it decrease.